# Elmah XML Logging on Load Balanced Environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah

We're implementing Elmah for an internal application. For development and testing we use a single server instance but on the production environment the app is delivered using a load balanced environment.

Everything works as charm using Elmah, except for the fact that the logs are done independant in each server. What I mean with this is that if an error happens in Server1 the xml file is stored physically on that server and the same for Server2, since I'm storing that files on the App_Data

When I access the axd location to see the error list, I just see the ones of the server that happened to attend my request.

Is there any way to consolidate the xml files other than putting them on a shared folder? Having a shared folder will make us to allow the user that executes the application on the server to have access to that separate folder and to be on only one of the servers instead of both.

I cannot use In-Memory or Database logging since FileLog is the only one allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider using [ElmahR](https://bitbucket.org/wasp/elmahr/wiki/Home) for this case, since you are not able to implement In-Memory or Database logging. ElmahR will provide you with a central location for the two load balanced servers to send errors to (in addition to logging them locally) via an Http post.  Then you can access the ElmahR site for to view an aggregated list. Also, ElmahR is storing the error messages in a SqlServerCE database, so it can persist the error messages it receives.

Keep in mind that if the ElamhR Dashboard app design does not meet your initial needs/desires, it could be modified as needed given that it is an open source project.

Hope this might be a viable option.